# How to allow Docker permission to create directory without sudo?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration

I am running a mongo container to dump a database. I cannot use sudo for the following docker command. How can I allow it to create that directory? Is there any workaround this?

```
docker run --name mongocontainer65 mongo mongodump --host HOST —username ADMN —password PASS --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --db cmsDev --out /tmp/jenkins_workspaces/full_deploy/

2018-05-01T11:57:29.285+0000    Failed: error dumping metadata: error creating directory for metadata file 
/tmp/jenkins_workspaces/full_deploy/cmsDev: mkdir 
/tmp/jenkins_workspaces/full_deploy/cmsDev: permission denied
```

Comment: Try with an export directory to $HOME

Comment: You can grant proper permissions to the user you use in docker.

Comment: How can I get the username I am using?

Comment: @configureMe  run `whoami` from your docker shell

Answer (score 0):

`/tmp/jenkins_workspaces/full_deploy/` I guess is a directory on your host machine. I think you have missed the mount the host volume to the container.